# Adding a second one-to-one relationship with table Entity Framework 6 fluent api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've been task with creating a web app using code-first, I've added a first one-to-one relationship which works as I expected, I then added a second one-to-one relationship but can't get it to work.

Here are my models (most properties removed for brevity)...

***FollowUpAssessment.cs***

```
public class FollowUpAssessment
{
    [Key]
    public int FollowUpAssessmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual FullBloodCount FullBloodCount { get; set; }
    public virtual AdverseEvent AdverseEvent { get; set; }
}
```

***FullBloodCount.cs***

```
public class FullBloodCount
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FollowUpAssessment")]
    public int FollowUpAssessmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual FollowUpAssessment FollowUpAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

***AdverseEvent.cs***

```
public class AdverseEvent
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("FollowUpAssessment")]
    public int FollowUpAssessmentId { get; set; }

    public virtual FollowUpAssessment FollowUpAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

***Context***

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FollowUpAssessment>()
                    .HasOptional(s => s.FullBloodCount)
                    .WithRequired(s => s.FollowUpAssessment);

        modelBuilder.Entity<FollowUpAssessment>()
                    .HasOptional(s => s.AdverseEvent)
                    .WithRequired(s => s.FollowUpAssessment);
}
```

When adding a follow up the full blood count data is added to its table correctly with the foreign key, but try as I may I cannot seem to make the adverse event data populate the table.

I've spent most of today looking at this, and have search the internet and only seem able to find .NET Core solutions for this. I'm having to work with .NET 4.7.1, MVC 5 and EF 6.2.0 to complete this task. I would be grateful for any suggestions to make it work as needed thanks!

Comment: I would recommend introducing independent property for primary key for both `AdverseEvent` and `FullBloodCount`.

Comment: Please also show the code that populates the tables.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this issue, it wasn't related to the fluent API code that I was working on at the time - it was related to a DateTime problem.